# ASP.NET MVC execution Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am planning to increase execution timeout of a MVC Controller method, and i am using below code for same :
My question is : This ChunkSave method gets called for each and every file, let's say if i am uploading 10 files it will be called 10 times for each file, so when i am setting the execution timeout it gets called each time. So is it okay that it gets called every time or it has to be only executed for the first time ?

```
public ActionResult ChunkSave(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string metaData)
        { 
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000;
           //logic for upload goes here
        }
```

Comment: You are setting this property for the current context. The next request will have a different context, so it will have to be called every time. Altough, this being classic .Net. You might need to increase the request timeout on IIS as well, if not already done.

Comment: @Marco : Do you mean Connection-timeout at AppPool in IIS ?

Comment: this solution solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474157/executiontimeout-in-asp-net-mvc-solved

Comment: i tried this solution and it work fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474157/executiontimeout-in-asp-net-mvc-solved